# How to add sorting to a column with dynamic data in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a column `Average` that gets the value :total from db and we are doing `total/3` in average column. as follows

```
index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
     column 'Average', sortable: true do |object|
      object.total/3
    end
end
```

I want to add sorting to this column. Can someone please help me with this one?..

Comment: can you use pagy library?

Comment: Is ```total``` a column in the db?  Then ```column 'Average', sortable: :total do ``` will suffice. If total is a calculated property, you may want to add a ```before_update :hook``` in your model and cache the results in a separate column in your model, perhaps called ```:average```